# Using different stylesheets in express/ node/ ejs application - style not defined

Tags: css, node.js, express, ejs

I want to use different stylesheets in my express/node/ejs project.
I want to render a view with specific style, so in the app.js I do this:

```
app.get('/mySite', (req, res) => {
res.render('mySite', { style: mySite });
```

Say I made this mySite.css and in the boilerplate.ejs I made a link to styles:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/stylesheets/<%=style%>.css">
```

How should I define 'style' not to get an error "style is not defined"?

Sorry if this is basic express knowledge I should have, but I'm still learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I learned that it can be done via appropriate reference to style in the route, while in the boilerplate there must be an ejs syntax for style reference

Answer (score 1):

I'm also learning and this same approach worked fine for me by defining an object of the stylesheet names in my controller.js file.

```
const styles = {
  index: "styles",
  register: "register",
  login: "login",
};
```

Then just added the style attribute to the rendering of each page:

```
const mainController = {
  index: (req, res) => {
    res.render("./products/index", {
      showRoom: productCollection,
      style: styles.index,
    });
  },
  register: (req, res) => {
    res.render("./users/register", {
      style: styles.register,
    });
  },
  login: (req, res) => {
    res.render("./users/login", {
      style: styles.login,
    });
  },
};
```

This way whenever index, register, etc... is rendered it calls for the name of the stylesheet to complete the href in the HTML:

```
  <!-- APPLIES EACH SPECIFIC STYLESHEET TO EACH SITE -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/<%= style %>.css" />
  <!-- ------------------------------------------------- -->
```